# RegEx for non-decimal with minimum length

Tags: c#, asp.net, regex

I know the RegEx for non-decimal(whole numbers) which is `^\d+$` however I want to know the RegEx for non-decimal with minimum length of 8?

Answer (score 2):

```
^\d{8,}$
```

.....................

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
^\d{8,}$
```

If it's within a reasonable range, you can make it faster and do something like:

```
long n;

if(long.TryParse(myString, n) && n > 9999999) {
    // It's valid
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`^[0-9]{8}[0-9]*$`

Digits 0 through 9, occuring 8 or more times, with nothing before or after.

Answer (score 0):

`\d{8}` should work

> `d` Matches a "d" character. Case sensitive
> `{8}` Match 8 of the preceding token
>
> Source: [RegExr](https://regexr.com/6a98i)